# deselectRowAtIndexPath has no effect on a grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Grouped UITableViews don't appear to automatically animate the deselection of a row in the same way that plain UITableViews do, for example when a UITableViewController appears again after a detail view controller is pushed and subsequently popped. The iPhone Settings app does appear to implement this behaviour however.

I have tried to implement the behaviour in the viewWillAppear method of my grouped UITableViewController class but it simply has no effect:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

//If returning from an edit then animate the deselection of the previously selected row
if ([self currentIndexPath] != nil) 
{
    [[self tableView] deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self currentIndexPath] animated:YES];
    [self setCurrentIndexPath:nil];
}
...
```

The row and section properties of `[self currentIndexPath]` are always correct and valid according to my UITableView but the row deselection still does not animate. I've also tried deselecting the row using the following, again without success:

```
[[self tableView] deselectRowAtIndexPath:[[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Please could someone help to shed some light on how this behaviour is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your indexpath correct?

I've absolutely no problems with this. Did you connect your TableView with self.tableview (if using an outlet connection)?

Best,
Christian

Comment: Hi Christian, my class inherits from UITableViewController so I use it's tableView. The index path is definitely correct, the section and row always relate to the table section and row that was selected. I've noticed that a lot of 3rd party apps also don't behave in this way but that the Apple apps do. Have you had this working on a grouped UITableView?

Comment: That's great thank you. My implementation doesn't use a .xib so I can only assume that Interface Builder is generating something to implement it and I am missing a detail when setting up my table view programmatically.